# read radio input inside editItemTemplate from server side in Radgrid

Tags: telerik, radgrid

i have an edit Item template inside a grid , as shown in the code below:

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="<%$Resources:Resources,Sex  %>" UniqueName="EmpSex" DataField="sex"> <ItemTemplate> <asp:Label ID="EmpSexLb" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("sex") %>'></asp:Label> </ItemTemplate> <EditItemTemplate> <input type="radio" name="Sexe" id="Radio1" checked="<%# Eval("sex").ToString()=="M"? "checked":"" %>"/> male  <input type="radio" name="Sexe" id="Radio2" checked="<%# Eval("sex").ToString()=="F"? "checked":"" %>"/> female </EditItemTemplate></telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

how can i read radio input from server side inside itemCommand event of radgrid ??

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the below code snippet.

ASPX

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <input type="radio" name="Sexe" id="Radio1" checked="true" runat="server" />
                        male 
                        <input type="radio" name="Sexe" id="Radio2" runat="server" />
                        female
                    </EditItemTemplate>
 </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

ASPX.CS

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == RadGrid.UpdateCommandName)
    {
        GridEditableItem item = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputRadioButton Radio1 = (item.FindControl("Radio1") as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputRadioButton);
        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputRadioButton Radio2 = (item.FindControl("Radio2") as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputRadioButton);
        //Access your radio button here
    }
}
```

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: i cannot use runat="server" in my code because i use Eval as shown in  code snippet above

Comment: If you do not want to use runat="server" then you have to use either http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/ajax/examples/manager/clientsideapi/defaultcs.aspx OR __dopostback in javascript. Let me know if any concern.